# C# Declare different database-types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, declaration

We have currently four different servers. On each server there is a database with one table. They are all named the same and the columns of the table are also exact the same.

I would like to choose a database based from a parameter.

My first though is to create some if-statements and declare it within.
Turns out this will be a scope-problem:

**If-Else statement**

```
string db = "db1"; // some input to say which database I want

if (db == "db1") {
  Database1 database = new Database1();
} else if (db == "db2") {
  Database2 database = new Database2();
} else if (db == "db3") {
  Database3 database = new Database3();
} else if (db == "db4") {
  Database4 database = new Database4();
}

// This will be a scope problem. Variables that are declared within a scope will be lost once you get out.
```

Next thing I tried is using Enum with a switch. Unfortunately once you declared "database" you cannot change the type afterwards

**Enum and switch**

```
public enum dataBases{
  None,
  db1,
  db2,
  db3,
  db4
}

dataBases dbases

switch (dbases) {
  case dataBases.db1:
    Database1 database = new Database1();
    break;
  case dataBases.db2:
    Database2 database = new Database2();
    break;
  case dataBases.db3:
    Database3 database = new Database3();
    break;
  case dataBases.db4:
    Database4 database = new Database4();
    break;
}
```

The last thing I tried is creating a null-variable, but this fails immediately without the if/else-story behind it:

**Null variable**

```
var database = null;
database = new Database1();
```

I'm working with C# / MVC for a couple of months, so I don't know all the in's and out's of this. Hopefully you can help me out.

Note: I have search on many terms in StackOverflow, unfortunately there were no suitable results for me.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: So do you need to use the `database` variable once it has been initialized? Do the classes have common methods?

Comment: use an interface:Database1: IDatabase , then IDatabase db; db = DataBase1, ect

Comment: Sounds like you need a property to define the database rather that a class per database ?

Comment: Hello Ric,

Yes, after these blocks of code I query some results from database. But it won't always be the same database. Sometimes they need information about Database1, Database2, etc.
That is why I would like to choose.

About the methods: All databases are exact the same. I created a "Database-first" approach to creat the model. (Hopefully this is the answer you expected?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was a totally different approach that we have discussed here.

Because all tables / databases are the same, there was no need to create extra models from all other databases again.
One model is enough, you only need to change the connection string when you create the DbContext.

I did this by adding a parameter in the DbContext, like the following:

***In the "Context.cs"-file***

```
public partial class ConnDatabase : DbContext {
  public ConnDatabase(string db)
    : base(db) {
  }
}
```

**Declaring database**

"*db*" is the name of the connection string in the *Web.config*-file. You need to pass it right here:

```
ConnDatabase database = new ConnDatabase(db);
```

For example:

```
ConnDatabase database = new ConnDatabase(database1); // Connect to database 1
ConnDatabase database = new ConnDatabase(database2); // Connect to database 2   
ConnDatabase database = new ConnDatabase(database3); // Connect to database 3   
ConnDatabase database = new ConnDatabase(database4); // Connect to database 4
```

This way you don't have to create multiple models for each (same) database. Another benefit of this is that you can simply add more databases without great changesin the code.

I would like to thank you all for your help and support the last couple of days!

Comment: Actually it is simple and clean

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understand what you're asking so here is one way of going about it:

Create an interface:

```
public interface IDatabase
{
   //methods/properties here
}
```

Create your classes:

```
public class Database1 : IDatabase { }
public class Database2 : IDatabase { }
public class Database3 : IDatabase { }
```

Create a method to return an `IDatabase` depending on your `enum`

```
public static IDatabase GetDatabase(dataBases db)
{ 
    IDatabase d = null;
    switch(db)
    {
         case databases.db1:
              d = new Database1();
         case databases.db2:
              d = new Database2();
         //add new cases for each enum value
         default:
               break;
    }
    return d;
}
```

So providing you pass in a suitable parameter value for `db`, then you will get the correct object back from the method that you can then use elsewhere in your code.